# Не могу найти ошибку в коде pascal

Tags: pascal

Вот код получается, вроде бы правильный,НО, по логике должно считать сначала Y1 потом Y2 потом те значения которые мы получили должно вычесть. Но что у меня получается Y1 не считает выдаёт нули, и не отнимает значения. Где я допустил ошибку?

```
program RIAD;
    var
      i, j, n1, n2: integer;
      Y1, Y2, Y3: real;
    begin
      write('vvedite n1= ');
      readln(n1);
      write('vvedite n2= ');
      readln(n2);
      Y1 := 1;
      for i := 3 to n1 - 1 do
        Y1 := Y1 + (1) * 1 / i;
      writeln('Y1=', Y2:8:4);

      Y2 := 1;
      for j := 2 to n2 do
        Y2 := Y2 + (1) * 1 / i;
      writeln('Y1=', Y2:8:4);
      readln;
      Y3 = Y1 - Y2;
       writeln(Y3);
    end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы похоже перепутали имена переменных просто:

```
program RIAD;
var
  i, j, n1, n2: integer;
  Y1, Y2, Y3: real;
begin
  write('vvedite n1= ');
  readln(n1);
  write('vvedite n2= ');
  readln(n2);
  Y1 := 1;
  for i := 3 to n1 - 1 do
    Y1 := Y1 + (1) * 1 / i;
  writeln('Y1=', Y1:8:4);

  Y2 := 1;
  for j := 2 to n2 do
    Y2 := Y2 + (1) * 1 / i;
  writeln('Y2=', Y2:8:4);
  readln;
  Y3 := Y1 - Y2;
   writeln(Y3);
end.
```

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/1nwZV3)

```
n1 := 5; 
n2 := 6;
```

для примера переменные проинициализированы явно:

```
vvedite n1= vvedite n2= Y1=  1.5833
Y2=  2.2500
Y3= -0.6667
```

Comment: Вау спасибо, но как сделать что бы оно эти значения отнимало?

Comment: Отнимает, пропустили `:` еще после `Y3`

Comment: подожди, в коде который ты мне предоставил двоеточие ведь есть, я его компилил. И все равно не отнимает

Comment: дополнил ответ, на IDEONE Y3 вычисляется правильно

Comment: Тю и правда, спасибо это может значит что-то у меня с компелятаром.

Comment: `(1) *` - и вот эту часть тоже уберите из формулы, ни на что не влияет